# Django textile not returning results for some content

Tags: django

I've noticed that for an event with a description below using `{{ event.content|textile }}` returns text. textile version 2.2.2

> This is a night of pure inspiration with some truly great people who have refused to follow the masses.They are determined to be at the top, all for a good cause.
>
> It doesn't get better than this! November 6th at St. Andrew's Church. Admission is Absolutely free! Invite your friends, family and your colleagues. Make a date and don't be late.

But for an event with the content below returns nothing back.

> Mutinda from Kenya - winner of the International Songwriting Competition 2010 World Music Category - is a strong singer/songwriter, vocalist and acoustic guitarist playing World Music and afro-folk, which contains rare sounds of Kenyan Music meeting the global contemporary influences of today.
>
> Mutinda is a self-taught musician who began pursuing his career in his childhood by playing a home-made guitar.
>
> Growing up in a typical rural setting and later living in one of the toughest neighborhoods in Nairobi, has made Mutinda interact with all kinds of people, whose lives and choices give him inspiration to share his messages, and be an encouragement, a hope and motivation for change.
>
> For Mutinda music is an opportunity to share his inner realizations and truths and to connect with people through a personal life experience.
>
> Since 2005 when Mutinda was one of the top artists in the Alliance Francaise “Spotlight on Kenyan Music” competition his professional music career has grown steadily taking him to places like Sauti Za Busara Festival in Zanzibar and on tour in Scandinavia.
>
> Under the indie-label metta metta ART, Mutinda released his first solo album – entitled “Matopeni” – in 2009.
>   Performing either alone, with a 5 piece band, a Kenyan or a Danish band, Mutinda passionately prefers playing the guitar during his concerts. “Music is that which takes you to a place where only uncertainty prevails; yet anchoring you here.”, he says.
>
> Besides making music, Mutinda is the founder of Iwayo Arts Centre - an NGO working with youth from the ghettos and slums of Nairobi. Through music Iwayo encourages the youth to know life to be more than their environment and that it is possible to find grace and humbleness in the midst of the toughest life-conditions.

Comment: I guess the content is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the tags `“` and `–` textile doesn't deal with non unicode characters